# Est-ce que l'on « apparie un appareil à un autre » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes, terminologie, informatique

> On peut également, mais c’est facultatif, l’**apparier** [l'appareil] en Bluetooth à son téléphone avec l’application [...] ([Lapresse.com](https://www.lapresse.ca/affaires/techno/201909/01/01-5239457-et-pourtant-il-lave-.php))

Le verbe [*apparier*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/apparier) a plusieurs sens, *rendre pareil, mettre en harmonie, accoupler, assortir par paires* etc. mais les substantifs [*appairage*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26538888) et *appariement*  font l'objet d'un grand nombre d'emplois techniques variés qui n'ont rien à voir. Il est question de la technologie [Bluetooth](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8873072) permettant à des appareils d'*échanger entre eux*.

- Pourquoi trouve-t-on qu'il est juste ou non de dire qu'on *apparie
  un appareil à un autre, deux appareils* dans ce contexte-là ; a-t-on un synonyme plus usuel ?

Comment: bonjour, merci de ne poser qu'une seule question à la fois afin de permettre les réponses spécifiques.

Comment: A mon humble avis, il y a d'une part la question sur l'emploi du verbe (apparier ou autre dans le cadre de la connexion de deux appareils, que j'aurais estampillée "synonyme") et, d'autre part, l'utilisation de la préposition "en" (dans le cadre spécifique du "Bluetooth" et avec les sous-questions, que j'aurais estampillée "grammaire"). J'y vois donc 2 questions et non trois (ou 4 si l'on comptait les points), ce qui semble être la même interprétation que les deux paragraphes dans la réponse actuelle.

Comment: @radouxju C'est raisonnable, merci. En fait la vraie question c'était probablement la préposition, c'était ce qui m'a accroché dans la phrase. Dépendamment des réponses peut-être que j'aurai l'occasion de présenter une autre question là-dessus.

Comment: en Bluetooth= quand vous utilisez Bluetooth ou sous Bluetooth. Sous Word,il est facile de trouver les fautes d'anglais (ou toute langue reconnue par le programme).

Comment: @Lambie Je ne comprends pas ton commentaire. La première phrase « en Bluetooth= quand vous utilisez Bluetooth ou sous Bluetooth »... ?? Je comprends parfaitement le sens, je m'intéresse au choix de la préposition. Ensuite, je pense que la deuxième phrase est un exemple, si tu utilises "\_" avant et après la phrase elle devient en italiques ds. les commentaires. J'aurais dit _avec Word/un traitement de texte_ mais en quoi est-ce applicable ici ? Stp fais une courte réponse si possible plutôt que d'avoir un long échange ici sur ce que tu veux dire et ce que ça signifierait pour la question.

Comment: "LG G3s : connecter un équipement en bluetooth https://assistance.orange.fr/mobile-tablette/tous-les-mobiles-et-tablettes/installer-et-utiliser/utiliser-internet-mail-et-cloud/internet/naviguer-sur-internet/lg-g3s-connecter-un-equipement-en-bluetooth_57390-58259 C'est bien lorsque vous utiliser le logiciel Bluetooth, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @Lambie Bluetooth n'est pas un logiciel mais bien une norme de communication (radio) permettant l'échange bidirectionnel de données ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth)) entre un périphérique et un mobile, par exemple. Hormis avec _en_, je peux entendre connecter avec _avec, sur, par, sous_. J'ai fait de la traduction de sites comme ceux que tu lies et leur choix ne fait pas autorité et en général ils ne font que se copier les uns les autres. Dans tous les cas tes commentaires ne répondent pas à la question. Tu sais, je suis un francophone, stp épargne-moi les généralités.

Answer (score 4):

Il me semble que d'autres verbes conviennent mieux, par exemple [jumeler](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jumeler), [associer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/associer) ou [appairer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/appairer).

Dans les trois cas, on jumelle/associe/appaire deux appareils **via** bluetooth, ou bien on jumelle/associe/appaire le périphérique **avec** l'ordinateur **via** bluetooth.

Comment: Dans les **trois** cas. Merci, j'ai corrigé.

Comment: Comment connecter mes accessoires (clavier, gamepad, etc.) en Bluetooth  ? https://www.assistance.bouyguestelecom.fr/tv-bbox/raccordement-decodeur-bbox-tv/connexion-accessoires-bluetooth-bbox-miami

Answer (score 3):

Entre deux appareils électroniques, on utilise majoritairement le verbe "connecter". Le verbe "apparier" (ainsi que d'autres propositions comme "jumeler" ou "associer") sera compris mais son usage paraîtra étrange.

Answer (score 2):

@Adrien

Le problème est que *connecter* ne correspond pas à la question du post initial.
Pour faire simple, il y a deux étapes :

- l'association (ou autre mot) entre les deux appareils à faire en premier lieu pour que les deux appareils soient validés pour se connecter entre eux par la suite. Cette étape n'est à suivre qu'une fois, à moins d'avoir supprimé cette *association*.
- la connexion que l'on établit par la suite à chaque fois que l'on veut utiliser ses deux appareils avec le Bluetooth

Le mot *connecter* correspond à l'utilisation, donc la deuxième étape qui sera à effectuer à chaque fois que l'on veut s'en servir.
Pour la première étape, il faut bien un autre mot que *connecter*, et dans les appareils, elles est souvent nommée *association*.