# (Verbe) un appareil à un autre « en/avec/sous/par etc. Bluetooth » ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, prépositions, informatique, en

> On peut également, mais c’est facultatif, l’apparier [l'appareil] **en** Bluetooth à son téléphone avec l’application [...] ([Lapresse.com](https://www.lapresse.ca/affaires/techno/201909/01/01-5239457-et-pourtant-il-lave-.php))

Il est question de la technologie [Bluetooth](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8873072) permettant à des appareils d'*échanger entre eux*.

- Quel sens de la préposition [*en*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en) emploie-t-on (la matière, la
  méthode ?) et pourquoi, est-ce surtout dicté par le verbe, serait-ce différent avec un autre verbe (*[jumeler](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/38369), [connecter](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/38415)*, par exemple) ; y aurait-il une nuance dans l'exemple si on avait employé *avec*, 
  *sous*, *par* ou autrement, est-ce relié à la manière d'analyser ce qu'est *Bluetooth* ?

  - Pense-t-on qu'on emploie la préposition *en*
    plutôt qu'une autre afin d'éviter la confusion, vu qu'on a aussi le complément du verbe *à son téléphone avec l'application* ?

    - Le cas échéant est-ce fréquent de recourir à ce genre de procédé quand on a plusieurs compléments ?

Comment: Salut, pourquoi avoir editer votre question ici, https://french.stackexchange.com/q/38363/13244 pour redemander ici ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 Il est préférable de se concentrer sur un sujet à la fois et d'ailleurs un contributeur avait suggéré de scinder la question de l'emploi du verbe choisi dans la citation de celle du choix de la préposition avec _Bluetooth_. Et donc on a deux questions essentiellement distinctes à partir d'une même citation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans cette phrase, le verbe *apparier* exige un complément d'objet indirect introduit par *à*, lorsqu'un des éléments à apparier est le complément direct et l'autre est un complément indirect. (L'autre possibilité est que l'ensemble des éléments soient le complément d'objet direct.) Les autres compléments (« en Bluetooth », « avec l'application ») sont des compléments circonstanciels, dont la préposition est dictée par le sens et non par le verbe.

[Bluetooth](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) est un protocole de communication, c'est-à-dire un langage que parlent des ordinateurs. Il est logique d'utiliser la même préposition pour dire que deux personnes communiquent *en* français ou que deux ordinateurs communiquent *en* Bluetooth.

On peut aussi considérer, comme tu le fais, que Bluetooth est « une technologie ». Ce concept est suffisamment vague pour que ce soit un point de vue possible : la technologie Bluetooth est un ensemble d'outils liés au protocole Bluetooth. De même qu'on visse une vis *avec* un tournevis, on relie deux appareils *avec* Bluetooth.

On peut aussi considérer que Bluetooth est une méthode pour faire communiquer deux appareils. On pourrait faire communiquer deux personnes *par* téléphone, ou deux appareils *par* un fil, mais ici les deux appareils communiquent *par* Bluetooth.

Je ne vois pas d'interprétation qui justifierai la préposition *sous*.

Le choix du verbe n'impose pas la préposition, mais il peut éventuellement orienter vers une des manières de considérer Bluetooth plutôt qu'un autre. Cela dit, l'influence du verbe reste faible. Par exemple *relier* suggère fortement « relier avec un fil », mais s'il n'y a pas de fil « [relier avec le wifi](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22relier+avec+le+wifi%22) » est nettement plus courant que « [relier en wifi](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22relier+en+wifi%22) ».

Je trouve que *en* est la préposition la plus naturelle ici, mais la présence de « avec l'application » pousse très fortement à ne pas utiliser *avec*. Il n'est pas interdit d'avoir deux compléments circonstanciels introduits par la même préposition, mais c'est très peu fréquent, parce que cela rend la compréhension difficile. Formuler la phrase « … apparier les deux appareils avec Bluetooth et l'application » serait un [zeugme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_(stylistique)), qui est une figure de style reconnue. Je crois que formuler « … apparier les deux appareils avec Bluetooth avec l'application » serait juste une maladresse.

Comment: _Sous_ ce serait l'idée du _protocole_ peut-être... on peut même imaginer _sur_, peut-être si on le voyait comme un _système_ ?! Dans la question liée une réponse emploie aussi _via_, c'est proche de _par_, le truchement, l'entremise. La nuance entre _via_ et _par_, le cas échéant, pour un autre jour...